# Subbasis of Product Topology

Tags: general-topology

There's a thing that confuses me about the product-topology. Namely, we said in class that the sets of the form $U_1 \times \cdots \times U_n \times \prod_{i = n+ 1}^\infty X_i$, where $U_i$ is open in $X_i$, form a subbase of the product $\prod_{n \geq 1} X_n$.

But isn't it also a basis? Because if I simply choose some of the $U_i$'s to be $X_i$, don't I receive all the elements that I'd get by intersecting the elements in the subbase?

So is there a difference between the basis consisting of elements $\prod_{n \geq 1} U_n$, $U_n$ open in $X_n$ and $U_n = X_n$ for all but finitely many, and the subbase described above?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's also a basis. No, there is no difference. A more interesting (in some sense) subbasis is the family of products where all but one factor are the whole corresponding space.